# How to modify marginTop by code?

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I'm trying to find a way to modify marginTop for an EditText by code...I read about setLayoutParams but I get ForceClose and this message :

```
08-05 14:53:59.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(913): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
08-05 14:53:59.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(913):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.findRoots(RelativeLayout.java:1291)
08-05 14:53:59.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(913):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1238)
08-05 14:53:59.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(913):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:279)
08-05 14:53:59.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(913):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:299)
08-05 14:53:59.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(913):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
```

Can anyone explain what should I do?

```
giveuser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
        giveuser.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

and in xml :

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/txt_username"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="350px"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_below="@+id/loginsubtitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dip" android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Identifiant" />
```

Comment: You have a cast exception, you're probably using findById with wrong casting. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
LayoutParams params = EditTextName.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
EditTextName.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: look for params.setMargins(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);

Comment: you are getting lp as linearlayoutparam. Get the edittext layoutparam.....That's why you are not getting your margin set ....

Comment: android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams haven't topMargin property.

Answer (score 0):

Class cast exceptions I normally find by my R file being out of date, try cleaning your project and re-building

Answer (score 0):

Instead of create a new `LayoutParams`, you have to get the `LayoutParams` from your `EditText`. You can try this:

```
EditText giveuser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
LayoutParams lp = giveuser.getLayoutParams();
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
giveuser.setLayoutParams(lp);
```